# How to initiate new profile object (has_one) after successful registration with Rails3 & devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, has-one

So I have devise setup to perform registration. After registration the user is redirected to profiles#new however I can't attach profile to current_user id

Actually it doesn't work at all. Here is what I have in my profiles_controller.rb

```
# POST /profiles
```

def create
    @profile = current_user.Profile.new(params[:profile])

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @profile.save
    format.html { redirect_to(@profile, :notice => 'Profile was successfully created.') }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
  end
end
```

end

leading to undefined method `Profile' for #

Answer (score 0):

So the `User` model `has_one :profile` ?

If so, you likely want:

```
@profile = current_user.profile.build(params[:profile])
```

Note that case ('profile' vs 'Profile') is important here.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately here is what happens undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass. It works when I do it in 2 steps. Any reason why? #@user = current_user
    #@profile = @user.create_profile(params[:profile]

Comment: Are you sure you have a `has_one :profile` (or `belongs_to :profile` ... depending on which has the foreign key) on the `User` model?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use

```
@profile = current_user.build_profile(params[:profile])
```

Check [rails api here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)